# Given that $x = 5\sin(3t), t\ge 0$: Find the maximum value of $x$ and the smallest value of $t$ for which it occurs.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, problem-solving

> Given that: $$x = 5\sin(3t), t \ge 0$$
>
> **Find the maximum value of $x$ and the smallest value of $t$ for which it occurs.**

I have figured out the smallest value by:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=15\cos(3t)$$

when $$15\cos(3t) = 0$$

gives us the smallest values of $t$: 30 degrees or $\frac{\pi}{6}$

From the provided answers, the maximum value of $x$ is 5, but I'm not sure how to obtain this. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to plug the value of $t$ ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The maximum value of $\sin 3t$ is $1$. So the maximum value of $5\sin 3t$ is $5$.

Comment: Glad I was ab;e to help :)

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x\leq 1$ and the smallest positive value of $x$ where $\sin x $ becomes $1$ is $\frac {\pi} 2$. Just put $x=3t$ in this and multiply by $5$.